# How can I convert a unix timestamps to UTC Date in MySql?

Tags: mysql, internationalization

I've a bunch of data stored in a mysql database as a bunch of unix style timestamps (in UTC). Previously, these have been formatted via Perl's `gmtime()`. It seems that MySQL's `FROM_UNIXTIME()` function tries to be helpful, and correct for daylight savings, but I *really* don't want it to.

Is there a nice handy method to convert the results from the system timezone (GMT/BST) to UTC or alternately determine if DST was in effect for a particular time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
mysql> SELECT NOW();
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2011-04-04 22:54:13 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @var = unix_timestamp(NOW());
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET time_zone='+00:00';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT NOW();
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2011-04-04 20:54:23 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(@var);
+---------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(@var) |
+---------------------+
| 2011-04-04 20:54:17 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

If you want to use named timezones, you can see [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html) for more information, and how to fill the timezone tables on your system.

Comment: This works great. Thank you Wrikken. I am just adding some code here for my reference so I don't forget when I search my favourites. 

set blahblah= convert_tz(from_unixtime(blahblah),@@session.time_zone,'+00:00');

Comment: Would be apt for a case by case basis indeed, so depending on whether you need _all_ date/time related fields to reflect another timezone, or just a _single_ one, choose one or the other.